# Pandas DataFrame.apply going very slow for scipy.stats

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy

I am trying to create a custom DataFrame.describe() function that will return

- numpy statistics
- scipy statistics
- quantiles from some source

This should reproduce my issue

```
# Python 3.6.6, Pandas 0.22.0

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sc

d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=100000))
d.apply(np.mean) #Works
d.apply(np.std) #Works
d.apply(sc.kurtosis) #Works
d.apply([np.mean, np.std]) #Works
d.apply([np.mean, sc.kurtosis]) # Gets stuck
```

It runs forever if I include the scipy functions, but finishes very quickly if I only use numpy. If there is a better way to mimic the output of pd.DataFrame.describe() with my own custom list of statistical output I am open to that too.

Comment: You mean `sc.stats.kurtosis` ? Also, what version of Pandas? As far as I'm aware `pd.DataFrame.apply` doesn't accept a list of functions.

Comment: Yes I do. I'm using a newer version of pandas which may be why it accepts lists as my code runs without error. I updated above to reflect yours.

Comment: Do you find the same problem when you use a list comprehension as in my solution?

Comment: Your solution runs just fine. The only issue now would be the output which I can probably configure. I see now that the np.mean returns a float64 while sc.kurtosis returns a 1-element array. I suspect that's related to the issue with my method somehow.

Comment: Probably, I suspect you can manipulate the output by retrieving the one-element array. It doesn't answer your question about `apply`, but we know *in general* `apply` is slow, even in the penultimate case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) isn't magic. It's just a Python-level loop and a convenience method. Except here, it doesn't add much convenience. It doesn't accept lists either, as it applies a *single function along an axis*, so your code is erroneous.

You can feed your dataframe as an argument to all these functions directly, and this exhibits consistent performance:

```
# Python 3.6.0, Pandas 0.19.2

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc

np.random.seed(0)
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=10**6))

%timeit np.mean(d)                                          # 1.3 ms per loop
%timeit np.std(d)                                           # 2.82 ms per loop
%timeit sc.stats.kurtosis(d)                                # 33 ms per loop
%timeit [func(d) for func in (np.mean, np.std)]             # 3.95 ms per loop
%timeit [func(d) for func in (np.mean, sc.stats.kurtosis)]  # 34.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think I can use this to get the result that I want with a bit of manipulation on the output. Thanks.